# Different HTTP response from inspector HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get data for the following website using requests and Scrapy Selector.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url="https://seekingalpha.com/article/4312816-exxon-mobil-dividend-problems"
headers = {'user-agent': 'AppleWebKit/537.36'}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
sel = Selector(text=req.text)
```

I could extract the text body but when tried to get the XPath for comments,

[image: XPath in Inspector]

I noticed that the HTML returned from `requests` is different from the inspector, therefore selecting the `class='b-b'` like,

```
sel.xpath("//div[@class='b-b']")
```

returns an empty list in Python. It seems that I'm missing something or the HTML is partially hidden from the bots.

After `view(response)` I found out the following is rendered,
[image: Error in handling comments]
**My Questions**

1. Why the same HTML cannot be seen in the HTTP response?
2. How to get the comments data using XPath expressions for this page

Answer (score 0):

Run your url link in scrapy shell and view the page by that command:

```
view(response)
```

your url link open in browser there you can see the source code and if the item is available there you can get it by xpath, simply inspect that element and copy that xpath you can get that element. i did not have my system. so i cannot send you exact code try the above things. your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, I did so and found out the "comments" section is not in the view(response). Do you have any suggestions to make it visible?

Comment: use selenium to get comments.

Comment: you can follow this website link "http://mroseman.com/scraping-dynamic-pages/", this will help you how you can use selenium with scrapy and you can get comment easily. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @ I ended up using Selenium in combination with Scrapy. The website you mentioned seems very relevant and helpful. Thanks